# Prevent gnome keyring password being reset after update

Tags: fedora, gnome, opensuse, gnome-keyring, seahorse

[Gnome Keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring) ([Seahorse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse_(software)) / Passwords & Keys GUI app) resets the default `Login` keyring's password when updating its associated package.

This is especially an issue on distributions with frequent updates as the keyring password has to be manually updated by the user after each update.

As I have full-disk encryption (FDE) and auto-login enabled, my `Login` keyring password is set to empty/blank value so that Gnome doesn't ask the keyring to be manually unlocked on each login.

How to fix this issue so that Gnome Keyring respects the existing password on package updates and not reset the password back to its original value?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround by following these steps:

1. Open Seahorse (Passwords & Keys) GUI app
2. Create a new keyring with a different name such as `mykeyring` and set it as the default
3. Delete the existing `Login` keyring.

Gnome Keyring re-creates the `Login` keyring after an update and sets its password to the default value but the new default keyring `mykeyring` is not altered.

The existing credentials (if any) stored in `Login` keyring would be lost on deleting it, I tried manually copying them over from `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring` to the new keyring file as I couldn't find a transfer/export option in Seahorse GUI but it did not work.